# SQL Average of average

Tags: sql, average

Hi I am struggling with the following exercise:

Find the difference between the average rating of articles released before 1950 and the average rating of articles released after 1950. (Make sure to calculate the average rating for each article, then the average of those averages for articles before 1950 and articles after. Don't just calculate the overall average rating before and after 1950.)

```
SELECT AVG(RatingBefore + RatingAfter) AS Difference FROM Rating
WHERE AVG(star) AND year >1950 AS AverageAfter
AND AVG(star) AND year<1950 AS AverageAfter
GROUP BY title
```

Is this code something that would work? I am new to SQL so please be nice if it is a mess. :) (It is not specified what type of SQL in the exercise I have been given.)

Comment: "WHERE AVG(star) AND year >1950 AS AverageAfter
AND AVG(star) AND year<1950 AS AverageAfter " is  completely wrong. In the where condition you specify the conditions of each row. It is not possibile to have a row that is older and also more recent of 1950. You can rename differently using CASE WHEN. Still not clear, do you need to show the two different avg or the difference of them as one result?

Comment: Aww.. Ok, thanks for letting me know. :) I have been using w3schools as my main resource but the complexity of the examples there are quite low.

Comment: @MiloBellano Only the difference of them as one result

Comment: w3schools is also known as "w3fools" and usually is not a good place to look for advice (the SQL part has many errors and I have been told that's true for HTML and CSS as well)

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess because we have no other info (sampel data, table structure, etc)

```
SELECT
  AVG(CASE year >1950 THEN star END) - AVG(CASE year < 1950 THEN star END),
  AVG(star)
FROM Rating
GROUP BY title
```

This is conditional aggregation to work out the before 1950 and after 1950 averages in the same query as the overall average.

Comment: The data structure is simple: 1 table “Ranking”, 4 columns “Id, title, year and star(1 to 5).